# Table data disappearing upon live search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am generating dynamic textboxes on button click in a table.
On button click i am calling **Details()** which appends a new row to the table:

```
  function Details(id,name)
{               
        var html = '';
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_id[]" value="'+ id +'" class="form-control item_id" autofocus required /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_name[]" value="'+ name +'" class="form-control item_name" required /></td>';
        html += '<td style="text-align:center"><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm order_item_remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';

        $("#table").append(html);
}
```

But when i try to live search the data from the table then its rows disappear.

Live Search:

```
$("#search_field").keyup(function() {
    var count = 0;  
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();

    $("#table").find("tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index === 0) return;
        var id = $(this).find("td").text().toLowerCase().trim();
        $(this).toggle(id.indexOf(value) !== -1);

        if(id.indexOf(value) !== -1){
            count = count+1;
        }
    });
});
```

Table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table">
                    <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
```

What am i doing wrong?? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "toggle(display): Use true to show the element or false to hide it".  Since everything is being hidden, it would suggest that `id.indexOf(value) !== -1` is always false.  If you provided more of an [mcve], it would be easier to confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this (edited to use non-ES6 syntax):

```
var rowMatches = $(this)
  .find(':input')
  .toArray()
  .some(function(input) { return $(input).val().toLowerCase().trim().indexOf(value) !== -1; });
$(this).toggle(rowMatches);
```

**Explanation**

[`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) is not meant to grab input vales.

You need to use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/). But since there can be multiple inputs per rows, you want to check whether at least one cell matches the filter.

- [`.toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/) transforms the set of nodes into an array,
- [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) returns true if at least one cell's value matches the filter string.

**Demo using the rest of your code**

```js
$("#search_field").keyup(function() {
  var count = 0;
  var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();

  $("#table").find("tr").each(function(index) {
    if (index === 0) return;

    var rowMatches = $(this)
      .find(':input')
      .toArray()
      .some(function(input) { return $(input).val().toLowerCase().trim().indexOf(value) !== -1; });

    $(this).toggle(rowMatches);

    if (rowMatches) {
      count = count + 1;
    }
  });
});

function Details(id, name) {
  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_id[]" value="' + id + '" class="form-control item_id" autofocus required /></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_name[]" value="' + name + '" class="form-control item_name" required /></td>';
  html += '<td style="text-align:center"><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm order_item_remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';

  $("#table").append(html);
}

Details(1, 'foo');
Details(2, 'bar');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<input id="search_field" placeholder="Filter"/>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help but its giving error on this line:
`.some(input => $(input).val().toLowerCase().trim().indexOf(value) !== -1);`

Comment: @CodingFreak Try the updated version, it uses non ES6 syntax which is more compatible. If you're still getting an error, please post what it says.

Comment: **Jeto** you are a genius. Thanks a ton mate. Cheers